# Send AJAX calls from main domain to subdomain

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I know this may have been answered already but none of the solutions I found are working for me.

I have an AJAX call from [example.com](https://example.com) to [api.example.com/v1](https://api.example.com/v1), when sending the request, no cookie is sent.

**EDIT:**

My `AJAX` code is

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"https://api.example.com/v1/",
    data: payload,
    processData: false,
    xhrFields: { withCredentials:true },
    crossDomain: true,
    xhrFields: { responseType: 'arraybuffer' },
    dataType: 'binary',
    contentType: 'application/octet-stream',
    headers: { "Csrf-Token": csrfValue, "accept": "application/octet-stream"},
    success: function(res) {
        // Some code here
    }
});
```

**EDIT 2:**

The headers set by the server on the preflight request are:

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: Content-Type, Csrf-Token, Cookie
access-control-allow-methods: OPTIONS, POST
access-control-allow-origin: https://example.com
allow: OPTIONS, POST
```

**EDIT 3:**

My cookie values are:

```
Name: __Secure-Csrf-Token
Content: 4XAlnRWR95FKGcpYxZb6P9xxtFx1hP7XXU8rSShpnEY
Domain: .example.com
Path: /
Send for: Secure same-site connections only
Created: Wednesday, May 25, 2022 at 11:18:17 PM
Expires: When the browsing session ends
```

And yes, mi site uses `HTTPS`.

Comment: The cookie domain should be simple ```example.com``` and you dont need to cross domains in this case. its even better to not have cross domain if not needed. all the other configurations are good. if you need more detailed answer with examples let me know.

Comment: But then, what I am missing? I already tried setting the cookie `Domain` to `example.com`, but nothing...

Comment: are you writing the back end with node js? also can you edit your question and show me how you are using the ajax call? is it axios? do you pass width credential in the ajax request aswell?

Comment: No, with Actix.

Comment: also can you edit your question and show me how you are using the ajax call? is it axios? do you pass width credential in the ajax request aswell?

Comment: Done, I added my `AJAX` call.

Comment: the Ajax call seems to be ok.. on the backend are you enabling allow-credentials header aswell?

Comment: im not familiar with actix. but in node js it will look like this: `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);` and it will be inside app.use function..

Comment: it seems to be correct aswell.. it can be the way you are setting the cookie... when you inspect the front end and going to application tab, can you see the cookie there? is it secure? is it httponly? if its secure, are you using ssl?  but i guess you already did this debug..

Comment: Look at my new edit.

Comment: what about adding the name of the cookie `__Secure-Csrf-Token` to Access-Control-Allow-Headers.

Comment: But `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` is to set the allowed headers, and the one AJAX uses is `Cookie` which is already set.

Comment: inspect the page and check in the network tab, the get request that gives the csrf token, look at the headers, do you see there extra header like X-XSRF-TOKEN? do you see the cookies there?

Comment: Yes, it returns the following header: `set-cookie: __Secure-Csrf-Token=4XAlnRWR95FKGcpYxZb6P9xxtFx1hP7XXU8rSShpnEY; SameSite=Strict; Secure; Path=/; Domain=example.com`

Comment: and in the request header do you see the cookies? also do you see extra header for csrf?

Comment: On the `POST` request to the API endpoint, the header `csrf-token: 4XAlnRWR95FKGcpYxZb6P9xxtFx1hP7XXU8rSShpnEY` is present but there is no `Cookie` header.

Comment: im sorry but i really dont know, seems like everything you did is correct. i might miss something, but for me everything seems to be correct. i hope you  will find the solution. if so please post it here. its intresting to know what the bug is

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it looks like I was repeating the `xhrFields` param, so the first mention where I set the `withCredentials: true` was being overwritten.